# Energies involved in a Bloch wall dependent on lattice site $N$

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism

In a ferromagnet, two types of energies are involved in a Bloch wall as a magnetic dipole transverse across a Bloch wall of $N$ lattice sites, orientating from $0 \rightarrow \pi$:

1. Heisenberg exchange energy
2. Anisotropy energy

In such a setup:

The Heisenberg exchange energy involved(per unit area) is $E_{exchange \space energy} = \frac{JS^{2} \pi^{2}}{Na^{2}}$

The anisotropy energy involved (per unit area) is $\frac{NK}{2}$

The total energy (per unit area) as a magnetic dipole transverse across a Bloch wall over $N$ lattice sites, from $0 \rightarrow \pi$ is $\frac{JS^{2} \pi^{2}}{Na^{2}} + \frac{NK}{2}$.

In a text I am reading, it says that for large $N$, the Heisenberg exchange energy decreases which unwind the wall and makes the wall bigger; at the same time, the same value of $N$, the anisotropy energy increases which tightens the wall and make the wall smaller.

I struggle to understand why $N$ affects the size of the Bloch wall. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: I’m confused - isn’t $Na$ the thickness of the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a ferromagnet, two types of energies are involved in a Bloch wall as a magnetic dipole transverse across a Bloch wall of $N$ lattice sites, orientating from $0 \rightarrow \pi$...

> ...The Heisenberg exchange energy involved(per unit area) is $E_{exchange \space energy} = \frac{JS^{2} \pi^{2}}{Na^{2}}$

> I struggle to understand why $N$ affects the size of the Bloch wall. Any insights are appreciated.

Based on your equation for the exchange energy, it appears that your $N$ is literally the number of sites across the *width* of the wall. That is, the width of the wall is $Na$, where $a$ is the lattice spacing. So, $N$ clearly affects the size of the Bloch wall, since the width of the wall is proportional to $N$.

Comment: But why does larger $N$ leads to greater "unwinding" of the wall?

Comment: Here I think "unwinding" means that each spin has to turn less relative to its neighbor for a wide wall than for a thin wall. The thinnest wall would have one spin pointing to 0 degrees and one spin pointing to 180 degrees. For a wide wall (e.g., of width 1000) the angle between adjacent sites along the wall is less (e.g., only 0.18 degrees).